# Managed Bootstrapper does not install anything, if all msiPackages are configured perMachine

Tags: wix, burn

I am writing a custom bootstrapper application, that have to install 3 msiPackages(InstallScope is set to "perMachine" for all of them).
But the BA doesn't install any of them.
Here are the error messages from log file:

> Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe. Error
>   0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe. Error 0x800700e8:
>   Failed to send
>   BURN_ELEVATION_MESSAGE_TYPE_PROCESS_DEPENDENT_REGISTRATION message to
>   per-machine process. Error 0x800700e8: Failed to execute dependent
>   registration action. Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to
>   pipe. Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write send message to pipe. Error
>   0x800700e8: Failed to send message to per-machine process. Error
>   0x800700e8: Failed to save engine state in per-machine process.

When I run the bundle installer as administrator, all packages are successfully installed. It seems that BA need to be elevated, for installing perMachine.
As far as I know Engine.Apply() elevate the install process. And after call Engine.Apply(), appears UAC dialog. But msiPackages still could not be installed.

I experimented with the msiPacages configurations and got an interesting result. If one of the packages configured to perUser install, BA will work fine, and install all components without administrators privileges. But it is necessary to install all packages perMashine.

What may be wrong with my BA?

Comment: Something similar was discussed in [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/29905701/) and ended up as a bug in 3.6. BTW, what's your version of WiX? If it's not the latest, perhaps it's worth upgrading to the [recently released 3.10](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2015/09/07/wix-toolset-v3-10-released/) and try it once again.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I am using the latest version wix 3.10 released 9/07/2015.